# @Size, usando hibernate validator, acusa erro em valor que deveria passar na validação

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, validação, persistência

Tenho uma aplicação Java SE na qual não consigo utilizar a anotação @size.
Essa anotação é trabalhada pelo org.hibernate.validator.Size.

Tem um campo de usuário no modelo na qual faço assim:

`@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@Column(name = "CAMPO")
private String campo;`

Ao tentar salvar um objeto acusa uma InvalidStateException, dizendo que o valor da String campo, que recebeu o valor "3216549", deveria ter tamanho entre 1 e 30. Mas o valor deveria passar pela validação.

Eu tentei usar @length e não acusou mais este erro. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo com o @size? 
Li em alguns lugares que ele é mais recomendado do que o @length, por questões de compatibilidade e queria usá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente ambas são redundantes de acordo com a [Documentação do Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#validator-constraints):

Mas repare que no caso do Length, o campo na tabela terá o tamanho definido em Max, e este só é válido para Sctring.

Já o Size, pode definir ainda tamanho de outros objetos como listas por exemplo.

Comment: Eu estou utilizando String, então os dois teriam que funcionar da mesma forma. Mas o Size diz que o valor é inválido (o que está errado) e Length está trabalhando corretamente. Fiquei sem entender.